# Relevance of new parameters for DiagnosticDescriptor constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I used the `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre` for updating  my reference of my solution, apparently it seems now that the constructor of  `DiagnosticDescriptor` now accepts two more arguments.

1. `isEnabledByDefault`: `bool` - True if the diagnostic is enabled by default
2. `customTags`: `string`  - Optional custom tags for the diagnostic. See `WellKnownDiagnosticTags` for some well known tags

`WellKnownDiagnosticTags` defines two tags `Unnecessary` and `EditAndContinue`

What does these do in constructing a `DiagnosticDescriptor` ?

Answer (score 3):

`isEnabledByDefault` is self-explanatory: it controls whether the diagnostic should be enabled or not when an analyzer reference is first added. The scenario here is your analyzer might have a bunch of separate diagnostics in it, but not all of them are ones you want to foist on unsuspecting users.

`customTags` is a general way to mark that a diagnostic should be treated or displayed somewhat different than normal diagnostics. The "unnecessary" tag means that in the IDE we fade out the span that the diagnostic applies to: this is how we fade out unnecessary usings or casts or such in the IDE. In some fancy scenarios you might want to define your own, but for the most part you'll either leave that empty or pass Unnecessary if you want the different UI handling. The EditAndContinue tag is for errors that are created if an edit-and-continue edit can't be applied (which are also displayed somewhat differently)...that's just for us to use.

Comment: Can you clarify whether we have to make any changes other than that? I've noticed my project using the new constructors yesterday but after adding these two fields the diagnostics didn't work. I executed my test project with a new File->Roslyn->Diagnostic (which uses assembly version 6 instead of 7) and the exact same code aside from the constructor and it worked. What else do we have to do?

Comment: Are you upgrading your code from the preview we released at build to the new stuff? And you're running under the Visual Studio "14" Preview?